# If $abx^2 = (a-b)^2 (x+1)$ then $ [1 +(4/x)+(4/x^2)]^{(1/2) }=$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

As the title says.

I found this question in our next term's book.

A) (a+b)/(a-b)
B) (a-b)/(a+b)
C) a^2 +ab
D) none

Comment: $$\sqrt{1+\frac4x+\frac4{x^2}}=1+\frac2x$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearrange the given equation to get

$$\frac{ab}{(a-b)^2} = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2} $$

Now, $1 + \frac{4}{x} + \frac{4}{x^2} = 1 + 4(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2})$. So we have:

$$1 + \frac{4}{x} + \frac{4}{x^2} = 1 + \frac{4ab}{(a-b)^2} \\
= \frac{(a-b)^2 + 4ab}{(a-b)^2}\\
= \frac{a^2 + 2ab + b^2}{(a-b)^2}\\
= \frac{(a+b)^2}{(a-b)^2}$$

Hence,

$$\sqrt{1 + \frac{4}{x} + \frac{4}{x^2}} = \pm\frac{a+b}{a-b}$$